# JQuery Mobile, Querystrings and Multiple Page Id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having trouble figuring out where I am going wrong with my JQuery Mobile site.  I have a link to another JQuery Mobile page that uses a querystring.  The link looks like this.

```
<li><a href="section.php?d=sb&s=1">News</a></li>
```

All normal internal JQuery Mobile links do not produce the problem.  Only links that go to another JQuery Mobile page with a querystring produce this problem.  The problem is when the above link is clicked my dom goes from looking like this.

[image]

To looking like this.

[image]

Images are hard to see on SO, so here they are on imgur.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccVOn.jpg

These are firebug DOM views of what the initial page and second page looks like.  My question is why are there now two DOM element with the same exact ID?  This is, and correct me if I'm somehow wrong, not a valid HTML page once this link has been clicked.  If I am using querystrings in JQuery Mobile, then what best practice am I missing that is causing this problem?

What do I need to do to avoid the multiple ID's on the same page as they are causing problems with my javascript functions.  I'm baffled by this problem, but hopefully some JQM pro can explain to me what I'm doing wrong.  I'm sure it's something silly.

Comment: What if it's an ad, it will then be tracked twice!  Also this still doesn't change the fact that the page is invalid now, right?

Comment: Do you have templates that include "id" values for elements without somehow qualifying them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought I was doing something silly.  My index.php had a page with id="frontpage" along with my section.php had a page with id="frontpage".  I just gave the section.php page a new id and the page is now valid and my functions work properly.